# How to query a varchar2 field which has numerical values using order by desc in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have table with varchar 2 datatypes column now i want to fetch the records column and duration column in order by desc order but not working wat i expected.

Query :

```
select * from sampletable2
where code = 'C'
order by  duration desc ;
```

QUERY output looks like below :

```
    KeyNumber       ID    Code   BRANCH  records   Duration
             
    A907654234      4      C      ALA     100      99  
    A875678235      3      C      PHE     30       9  
    A123456789      1      C      HIE     78       45   
    A907863544      5      C      VAL     50       23
```

what i want is like :

```
    KeyNumber       ID    Code   BRANCH  records   Duration
    A907654234      4      C      ALA     100      99 
    A123456789      1      C      HIE     78       45 
    A907863544      5      C      VAL     50       23     
    A875678235      3      C      PHE     30       9
```

can someone correct me where im going wrong and correct my query?

Comment: I don't see how your query could produce the first result, regardless of data type, unless you have hidden characters in the data.  What are numbers being stored as strings?

Comment: Your query can't return the specified output, no matter what data type it is.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Looks like `records` column contains leading spaces, moreover, the amount of them vary from row to row.

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue on some online fiddle.

Comment: @Akina there is no leadinf spaces or rows vary fro other row . its just formating while typing here. just you ignore those

Comment: Please share the exact output of query1. The query and output of query 1 do not match.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
order by to_number(duration) desc
```

It should work, if `duration` contains numbers. Also, if that's so, why do you keep numbers in a `VARCHAR2` column?

---

If column contains something else, and not only numbers, then see whether regular expressions help. For example:

```
order by to_number(regexp_substr(duration, '\d+')) desc, duration
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_number` and `on conversion error` as follow:

```
order by to_number(duration default -1 on conversion error) desc
```

With this solution, you will get all the non number value records at last.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

I don't see how your query is producing the first result.  But if you want to sort by *numeric* values, then you can convert to a number:

```
order by to_number(records) desc, to_number(duration) desc ;
```

That said, a much better approach is to fix the data model.  You should not be storing numbers as strings.

Comment: tried earlier with to_number but its throwing invalid number

Comment: @HemanthTanna . . . Then you have bad data, and your question doesn't specify how to handle non-numeric data.